# Stange mysql_update function seems to only get $this-> info

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so for some reason I am only getting $this-> information getting sent to the mysql database

ie: it should be this

```
"UPDATE `shop_products` SET shopid = 1 WHERE id = 42"
```

but instead I am getting this

```
"UPDATE `shop_products` SET 1 WHERE 42"
```

Here is the code I am using.
I am not sure why this is not working

```
public function addstoreproduct($id,$shopid,$categoryid,$productname,$description,$price,$rcb)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->shopid = $shopid;
        $this->categoryid = $categoryid;
        $this->productname = $productname;
        $this->descriptionid = $description;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->rcb = $rcb;

        mysql_query("UPDATE `shop_products` SET shopid = "+$this->shopid+" WHERE id = "+$this->id+"");

        //$this->updatedb('shop_products','shopid='+$this->shopid+'','"id='+$this->id+'"');


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`mysql_query("UPDATE shop_products SET shopid = " . $this->shopid . " WHERE id = " . $this->id);`

Comment: Yeah I think he's got it. String concatenation in PHP is "." "+" doesn't work for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show the correct query when you build it first like so...

```
public function addstoreproduct($id,$shopid,$categoryid,$productname,$description,$price,$rcb)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->shopid = $shopid;
    $this->categoryid = $categoryid;
    $this->productname = $productname;
    $this->descriptionid = $description;
    $this->price = $price;
    $this->rcb = $rcb;
    $query = "UPDATE `shop_products` SET shopid = "+$this->shopid+" WHERE id = "+$this->id+"";
    echo $query;
    mysql_query($query);

    //$this->updatedb('shop_products','shopid='+$this->shopid+'','"id='+$this->id+'"');


}
```